# Roo not ignoring transient

Tags: spring-roo

I have this field in a @RooJavaBean;

```
@Autowired
@Transient
private transient MessageDigestPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

There is no getter or setter, the field is not in log.roo or the database. Grep'ing the entire project the field only appears in this bean and applicationContext.xml.

Every time I run the Roo console it insists on generating a getter and adding the field to the view, is there anyway to stop this?

This question shows-up a lot, never answered, I'm not holding out much hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to prevent Roo from generating fields marked as transient in the View.

The trick is to edit the views and mark any fields you don't want as `render="false"` and `z="user-managed"`

Answer (score 1):

RooJavaBean is meant to add bean methods to any class, it doesn't know about entities at all.
Entities may have Transient fields which mean they wont be stored in the database.

Typically, autowired is not used in entities, so there is no need to suppress getter/setter creation.  Also, RooJavaBean is not normally used on the service or repository classes, so no need to suppress getter/setter creation there either.

Comment: +1 for noticing the @RooJavaBean, I totally had tunnel vision on this and of course it's responsible for the getter/setter. Thanks. This is not The Answer however.